# ImageButton multiple screen in android

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm trying to make a calculator app but encounter difficulties when designing the interface for it
I want the button fill the screen horizontally. But they are too small. How to larger buttons and fit all screen sizes.
This is my code in .xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="8.5"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="duy.calculatordemo.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:background="#AAAAAA"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btntan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:src="@drawable/btn_tan"
        android:background="@null" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnsin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@layout/activity_main"

        android:src="@drawable/btn_sin" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btncos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@layout/activity_main"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_cos" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnlog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@layout/activity_main"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_log" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Can you help me! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for fill the background in `image button`. For more info try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).